# Public variable of code behind not working in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a public variable in code behind.
I want to access this in asp.net controls in .aspx file.
What should i do?
My code is:

```
default.aspx.cs
public partial class view_diamond : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string id;
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["diamond_id"];   
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            showData();
        }
    }
    protected void showData()
    {
        id = Request.QueryString["diamond_id"]; //value from query string.

    }
}
```

```
default.aspx
<asp:Label ID="diamond_carat_lbl" CssClass="diamond_carat_lbl" runat="server" Text="<%# id %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Why you are not assigning lable value in code behind itself when it is available?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

You need to Use `'<%=id %>'`

```
<asp:Label ID="diamond_carat_lbl" CssClass="diamond_carat_lbl" 
runat="server" Text='<%=id %>' ></asp:Label>
```

Desc:

`'<%#id %>'`: this is Used for Data Binding

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variable as:-

```
Text = "<%= id %>"
```

Please note, `<%# %>` code nugget is used for `Data Bound` controls, for accessing the public variables we can use standard content code nugget i.e. `<%= %>`.